# is there any method to get the row and column number in a uitextview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview, padding

I am trying to achieve a task in which the user the will create notes just like iNotes.app, for this i have to give some padding from left, in my case the padding is little more than the actual iNotes(app) and the problem with this is, If I complete the whole line it goes out of view/screen and user cant see.

To solve this Issue I first I used

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,40,0,-40);
//this thing makes the content non-scrollable horizontaly 
//but the text still goes out of screen
```

Then I used

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,40,0,0);
//By doing this the content becomes horizontally 
//scrollable and the content appear as per scrolling.
```

I don't want my textview to scroll Horizontally and I want it to show the content without cutting anything.

Please guide my what should I do to tackle this problem and 
If my approach is wrong please suggest any other way. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please try it without setting contentInset of textView. fix textView's width as per your device's screen width.

Comment: Thanks for your time Ravin and I am sorry that I didn't get what you exactly are trying to convey. Lets say i dont do any manipulations like contentInset and all that then how will I be able to get the row number and column number of the uitextview ?